# Inverse map for the isomorphism between $L_q$ and $L^*_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

I know that $L_q \cong L^*_p$ (the two are isomorphic) if $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Additionally, the map between the two $\phi : L_q \rightarrow L^*_p$ can be constructed as:

$$(\phi(g))(f) = F_g(f) = \int g(x)f(x)dx, g \in L_q, f \in L_p, F_g \in L^*_p$$

What would be the inverse map $\phi^{-1} : L^*_p \rightarrow L_q$ in that case? Is it a function $(\phi^{-1}(F)) \in L_q$ such that:

$$F(f) = \int (\phi^{-1}(F))(x)f(x)dx, \forall f\in L_p$$

Is this function $(\phi^{-1}(F))$ uniquely defined from the above?

Comment: Remark: The function itself is not uniquely defined - it is only uniquely defined up to its values on null sets (ie only as an equivalence class in $L_q$). Aside from that I think you are also getting yourself a bit confused here as your argumentation is becoming circular. If you know that $\phi$ is an isomorphism then $\phi^{-1}(F)$ has no choice but to be a unique element of $L_q$ and it certainly must satisfy the equation you write by definition.

Comment: @s.harp I guess put another way: I know that the integral is well-defined from Holder's inequality, but to get that the inverse is unique I need to have that $\phi$ is a bijection. By "I know that $L_q \cong L^*_p$" I meant that I know it because it's stated in what I am currently reading. It is not proven that the mapping is bijective there however, which I guess is where my confusion arose from. And indeed if I have this it would follow that $\phi^{-1}$ is unique.